# Analytics bundle for PHP Symfony framework

Tags: php, plug-in

I've been looking for a bundle to gather around some statistics about my Symfony apps. Something simple like the number of times a route has been accessed, maybe by user, to know who and how much is using the app.

I haven't found something already done yet, I could set some kernel listeners and log this info, but I suppose is something common so it kindda bugs  me that I haven't been able to find something around.

Have you guys seen something like that? If no, some advice on doing it by my own? I'm a little bit worried of adding to much overhead to the server making new database queries each time I get a request.

Comment: Welcome aboard, Mark. "`some advice on doing it by my own`" is off-topic here (click the question mark at the top right of any of our sites to discover what is on topic). "`Have you guys seen something like that`" would be better phrased something like "`can you recommend a library or plug-in for Symphony which does that?`". Despite that, I upvoted you :-) as it is basically a good question. Hope you get an answer.